# Typescript interface function member

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript. I couldn't understand the following use of interface:

Say, there is a function :

```
function test(arg1: ITest):number {
  return 20;
}
```

If the `ITest` interface is like below :

```
interface ITest {
    (props: string):number;
    a1?: number;
}
```

Then, the below call is valid :

```
const obj = {

   func: (p: string): number => (10+2),
};

test(obj.func); //Should not I pass obj instead of obj.func ?
```

Q: Should not I pass `obj` instead of `obj.func`?

But, if the interface is like below :

```
interface ITest {
        (props: string):number;
        a1: number; //Removed the optional sign "?"

}
```

Q: Then what argument should I pass to the test function ?

Q: what is difference between above interface and the following changed declaration of the interface?

```
interface ITest {
        func: (props: string)=>number; //changed it from (props: string):number;
        a1: number;
 }
```

Thank you for clearing out my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: Should not I pass obj instead of obj.func ?

`ITest` is a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types). It describes a function itself, not an object with a function property or method.

> Q: Then what argument should I pass to the test function ?

Now you have declared `ITest` as a function type with required property `a1`. The [property declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions) on a function works in TS by using a function declaration or `const` expression. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=52#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyxyAFAA5QD25WAXMjlKAOYCUDIArgLYBG0ANxEScAIydeAqMIC%20BAjC4gEYYFRDJIOUnCgsJaTDg7Ju-aPhHEoEMFyiaATAAY5ChBpzIlK5AF4ycgYmVlNzaQCAPmQxF2QAamQnRWUEADpxAOQAFhTPEG8qPgArbLwfNORZYW0wUmKS9N8ENmQAenbkAHcqKABrLDMqboUWtQ1KlScKELBmEHZJCyh8ZFt7R1j4pKdq1OnMsWyxAGYAdgICotK9wIqWvZqCOobb5rSnNs6evsHh7pAA):

```
const func = (p: string): number => 10 + 2 // or function declaration func(p: string) {...}
func.a1 = 42
const obj = { func };
test(obj.func) // works now
```

> Q: what is difference between above interface and the following changed declaration of the interface ?

`ITest` now has become an interface declaration for an object with `func` and `a1` properties.

```
const o1: ITest = {
    func: s => 137,
    a1: 42
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will start from what is function in JS/TS. Function is an object, that means that as any other objects function can have methods and properties. This is even visible in base function object, as it has methods like `apply` or `bind`. In any given moment you can attach property to any function. Consider

```
const f = (a:string) => a
f.prop = 1;

// take a type from f
type F = typeof f;
```

It is full valid TS code. And if we ask what type above function has it will be:

```
type F = {
    (a: string): string;
    prop: number;
}
```

As you can see above is close to your sample code. And indeed what we have here is function object in TS, it has main definition of functions in form of `(a: string): string;` and other properties like `prop` or in your example `a1`.

Its not a mistake that this definition is so similar to standard object type definition, as we said function is just an object.

If your function has no other properties you can define the type in two ways:

```
type F1 = {
    (props: string):number;
}
type F2 = (props: string) => number
```

Above `F1` and `F2` definition are equal, but the first one gives opportunity to append additional properties to function object, where the second does not allow on such.

How now we can create valid object of our function with property, consider following snippet:

```
interface F1 {
    (props: string):number;
    a1: number;
}
// below preparation of object by temporary f1
const f1 = (props: string) => 1
f1.a1 = 2;
const a: F1 = f1; // a is valid value type F1
```

In your example `a1` is optional so it doesn't need to be provided, that said such definition is valid:

```
const f1: F1 = (props: string) => 1
```

Ok, the last thing is object with `func` property, it is really a different thing.

```
const obj = {
   func: (p: string): number => (10+2),
};
type Obj = typeof obj;
```

If we check what is `Obj` type it is:

```
type Obj = {
    func: (p: string) => number;
}
```

So it is different type, it says we don't have function object, but an object with method `func`. We can easily compare both types

```
type FunctionType = {
    (props: string):number;
}
const f: FunctionType  = props => 1

type ObjectWithMethodType = {
    func: (props: string) => number
}
const obj: ObjectWithMethodType  = {
  func: props => 1
}
```

I hope this explanation helps.